# create two socket connection in one thread

Tags: android, sockets, client-server

In my application i want to share file between a server and client, for that purpose i want to create two socket connection in one thread.
For example at server we have thread "T" and it has opened two socket like "1234" and socket no "3456" now on the client thread "T2"  i will try to connect with these sockets.
So how i should implement it.

server:

```
thread 
{
wait at socket "1234"
wait at socket "3456"
}
```

CLIENT SIDE:

```
Thread 
{
connect with socket no "1234"
connect with socket no "3456"
}
```

Comment: What have you tried and why didn't it work? For instance, when you googled something like "java socket tutorial" and hundreds of relevant links appeared... what about them wasn't helpful?

Comment: @mah thanks dear, actually i am asking that whether i can communicate with two peers by using only one thread for both the connection, or i have to create different threads for each socket connection...please help

Comment: It's easier if you use two threads so they can operate independently. You can make this work with a single thread if your protocol is very specific and followed correctly, but this can often be more difficult than managing a second thread.

Answer (score 0):

if you have well implemented protocol(ie. each socket will send the data in a definite order), yeah one thread should work. but you can do this using only one socket connection too. what is the main point of creating two sockets? and what is the relation with android?

in addition; you definitely have to elaborate your question, otherwise it seems the question will be closed soon.

Comment: actually in one socket i am sending some condition variables and in other socket i am sending file data. so when i will send the condition variable(data) in first socket connection and it meet the desire then in the second connection i send the file. the main point is that, can  i create two socket connection in one thread and